# Mariadb server is always with 100% processor utilization but application servers are under utilized

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter, optimization, mariadb

My Mariadb installation works well with normal times. However during peak usage, all CPU cores are being utilized 100% constantly. There are around 250000 active users during peak usage times. The cores have been scaled vertically from 8 to 16 to 32 for now. I am still facing issues of high utilization of cores during peak times.
PFB the htop result:

```
All CPU Cores: 100%
Mem 5.25G/126G
Swp 0K/0K
Tasks: 43, 961 thr; 32 running
Load average: 150 148 148
```

The values of few important commands are below:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
1030492
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
4194304
cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
65530

innodb_buffer_pool_size=55G
max_connections        = 50000
```

MariaDB version: 10.6

Slow Query main issue:

```
# User@Host: lrp_dbuser[lrp_dbuser] @ lrp-application-server-2.internal.cloudapp.net [10.10.0.5]
# Thread_id: 3630886  Schema: lrp  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 50.155999  Lock_time: 0.049785  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 150617
# Rows_affected: 1  Bytes_sent: 52
SET timestamp=1666331690;
UPDATE `session_lrp` SET `timestamp` = 1666331640
WHERE `id` = 'pghjejnvf8ou61usog5983h6lihh4jr0';
# Time: 221021  5:54:51
# User@Host: lrp_dbuser[lrp_dbuser] @ lrp-application-server-2.internal.cloudapp.net [10.10.0.5]
# Thread_id: 3632952  Schema: lrp  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 50.334102  Lock_time: 0.050021  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 150632
# Rows_affected: 1  Bytes_sent: 52
SET timestamp=1666331691;
UPDATE `session_lrp` SET `timestamp` = 1666331640
WHERE `id` = 'hsun0ggh48i8t4pbv9u6ac2f13fdkujf';
# User@Host: lrp_dbuser[lrp_dbuser] @ lrp-application-server-2.internal.cloudapp.net [10.10.0.5]
# Thread_id: 3632570  Schema: lrp  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 59.245218  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 70
SET timestamp=1666331691;
SELECT GET_LOCK('62f67a85ee74fca9c3b3c30a20f70f82', 300) AS ci_session_lock;
# User@Host: lrp_dbuser[lrp_dbuser] @ lrp-application-server-2.internal.cloudapp.net [10.10.0.5]
# Thread_id: 3634754  Schema: lrp  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 15.116038  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 70
SET timestamp=1666331691;
SELECT GET_LOCK('6a046e7d67351ce96e8ed43e2c27eaed', 300) AS ci_session_lock;
# User@Host: lrp_dbuser[lrp_dbuser] @ lrp-application-server-1.internal.cloudapp.net [10.10.0.4]
# Thread_id: 3632996  Schema: lrp  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 50.000255  Lock_time: 0.050056  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 67
SET timestamp=1666331691;
UPDATE `session_lrp` SET `timestamp` = 1666331641
WHERE `id` = '67aofej14f1eq8aqobq0hecuh7qavp1d';
```

Please let me know what do i need to optimize.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @GeorgRichter Ok now?

Comment: include a link to `show global status` (after 24hrs uptime) and consider enabling the [slow query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log/) with [explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-extended-statistics/) and a [long_query_time](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#long_query_time) of the number of seconds you consider long for a query. Identify important ones and include `show create table tblname` for those referenced by the query.

Comment: 250K active users per second?  Per year?  (It is not possible to have that many simultaneous connections.)  What are the STATUS values of `Max_used_connections` and `Threads_running`?

Comment: "Mem 5.25G/126G" gives me a hint that assigning more memory to MySQL might not hurt.  see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lack of INDEX?**

```
# Query_time: 50.155999  Lock_time: 0.049785  Rows_examined: 150617
# Rows_affected: 1  Bytes_sent: 52
SET timestamp=1666331690;
UPDATE `session_lrp` SET `timestamp` = 1666331640
WHERE `id` = 'pghjejnvf8ou61usog5983h6lihh4jr0';
```

Is there an index on `id`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE session_lrp`

**Usage of GET_LOCK?**

```
# Query_time: 59.245218
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 70
SET timestamp=1666331691;
SELECT GET_LOCK('62f67a85ee74fca9c3b3c30a20f70f82', 300)
         AS ci_session_lock;
```

Please explain the usage of `GET_LOCK` -- It may be the cause of your problem.  And there may be a much better workaround.

**Timeout -> ROLLBACK**

```
# Query_time: 50.000255  Lock_time: 0.050056
```

Do you check for errors?  *The query was not performed!* Being that close to 50 seconds smells like you hit `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`.

Do not increase that setting.  Instead:

- fix the cause
- decrease the timeout
- change the code to detail with this and every other query that gets an error.

Comment: This is actually the table used by Codeigniter. I am using Codeigniter 3 php framework, with database sessions (due to multiple application servers).

Comment: Maybe Codeigniter is in the way?

Comment: Yes it seems Codeigniter is causing problems in sessions management. But session management is built in by default in the codeigniter framework.

Comment: Alas, a lot of my Answers on this site are to work around frameworks that get in the way of performance.  There are perhaps 100 frameworks, so I have not found the time to become an expert on any.

Comment: Its the issue with Codeigniter framework.